# processQueue not working when there is no new image added to Dropzone

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am incorporating Dropzone in my form, which contains other data. For the create process, it works well. Images can be dragged and dropped into the Dropzone box, and when the "Save_button" is clicked, the images will be submitted together with the rest of the form data.

I also used this same page, for the edit process, to allow users to edit the submitted images and other relevant data. Uploaded images are pulled and displayed in Dropzone through the code block "Block with uploaded images" below.

The problem arise here. If the user doesn't add any new image in Dropzone, then clicking on "Save_button" doesn't get the form to upload! I think processQueue doesn't do anything because the image queue is empty and thus not submitting the form.

Question: Is there a way, to force the form to be submitted? For example, trigger a "sendingmultiple" event so that the other form data can be submitted?

```js
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictDefaultMessage = "Drop images here to upload<br>(.jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png)";

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
url: '/addpage',
autoProcessQueue: false,
uploadMultiple: true,
parallelUploads: 5,
maxFiles: 5,
maxFilesize: 1,
acceptedFiles: '.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif',
addRemoveLinks: true,
init: function () {
   dzClosure = this;
   myDropzone1 = this;

   //Block with uploaded images, start
   var imagesList = ["http://www/path/to//image1.jpg"]
   
   for (var i = 0; i < imagesList.length; i++) {
       var mockFile = { id: i, name: "Image " + i, filename: imagesList[i], size: 1, type: "image/jpg", status: Dropzone.QUEUED, accepted: true, upload: {} };
       myDropzone1.emit("addedfile", mockFile);

       myDropzone1.createThumbnailFromUrl(mockFile, imagesList[i], "", "");
       myDropzone1.files.push(mockFile);
       myDropzone1.emit("complete", mockFile);
   }
   //Block with uploaded images, end

   document.getElementById("Save_button").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();

       var success = true;

       if (!someFormValuesValidation())
           success = false;

       if (!success) {
           alert("Form validation failed, please check values.");
           return false;
       }
       else {
           dzClosure.processQueue();
       }
   });

   this.on("sendingmultiple", function (data, xhr, formData) {
       $('#loading').show();

       formData.append("Title", jQuery("#Title").val());
       formData.append("Price", jQuery("#Price").val());
       formData.append("Quantity", jQuery("#Quantity").val());
   });

   this.on("successmultiple", function (file, result) {
       if (result.Response == "0") {
           alert("Success!");
       } else {
           alert("There is a problem: " + result.Error);
       }
       file.status = Dropzone.QUEUED;
       myDropzone1.status = Dropzone.QUEUED;

       $('#loading').hide();
   });

   this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
       this.removeFile(file);
       alert("Can't add more images. Maximum only 5 images");
   });

}
}
```

```html
<form action="/addpage" autocomplete="off" id="Form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
    <input name="Images" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="save-btn" id="Save_button">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I think `processQueue` doesn't do anything because the image queue is
>   empty and thus not submitting the form.

Yes, the queue is indeed empty — run `console.log( myDropzone1.getQueuedFiles() )` on the browser console and you'd get an empty array (`[]`).

> Is there a way, to force the form to be submitted?

In your `mockFile`, set the `status` to `Dropzone.QUEUED`:

```
var mockFile = { ..., status: Dropzone.QUEUED, ... };
```

And the `mockFile` needs to have a `upload` item, which can simply be `{}` like so:

```
var mockFile = { ..., status: Dropzone.QUEUED, accepted: true, upload: {} };
```

### UPDATE

The previous answer was actually meant to enable the form to be *simply* submitted **without the binary image data** — i.e. the `QUEUED` status and `upload` item are only for making the "Save" button works.

But if you actually intend to upload back all the images in the `imagesList` array, then the `mockFile` should be a valid [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object/instance, and I would use `Dropzone.prototype.addFile()` to add the file to the Dropzone.

And for that reason, your `for` loop could be as simple as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imagesList.length; i++) {
  let name = imagesList[i];
  name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

  fetch(imagesList[i])
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      let file = new File([blob], name, blob);
      myDropzone1.addFile(file);
    });
}
```

Comment: I followed your snippets, and there is some great improvements now. But still not fully working. 

On the edit page, when I click on the Save_button, the form seems to be submitting, but I think it never actually gets submitted. The ajax animation is shown and remains so for like forever. The breakpoint i set in the addpage is never hit. (In the codes above, I have omitted the ajax animation which will be displayed when the form is submitting and hidden when it is done)

Comment: Can you create a CodePen or JSFiddle with the code you use? Did the console show any errors?

Comment: I mean, the full code that you use. Or you can add the code to the question as a working snippet.

Comment: I have updated the code to the question, incorporating your code and updating it as close to the code in my project as possible, neglecting the bits which I think is irrelevant. The $('#loading').show(); will show an overlay animated gif, and this is being shown like forever when I click on the Save_button. I am not sure how to make this work in CodePen or JSFiddle. Please help, thank you so much.

Comment: I noticed this. The image (this one -> http://www/path/to//image1.jpg) in Dropzone, has remove link with text "Remove file". After I click on Save_button, this text changes to "Cancel upload" and #loading is shown... these go on forever... But the submission never reach the addpage I think as the breakpoint I set in the addpage is never triggered. Please help, thank you so so much.

Comment: Are you actually uploading back all the images in the `imagesList` array? Or are you just editing their properties - e.g. the "Price" field? If it's the former, then check the updated answer.

Comment: I saw in Firefox web console the following error, after I click on the Save_button:
TypeError: Argument 2 of FormData.append does not implement interface Blob.

Yes, I intend to upload back all the images, as I find this is easier than to potentially remove some existing images and maybe add a few new images.

Ok, I will use your new codes and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not getting that FormData error - neither with your original code ([or this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53554327/3)) nor the new one I provided. So I'm not sure why you got that error. Have you tested the new code?

Comment: Yes, I have tested the new code and it works as expected. But, now I start to realize this might not be a desired method for long run, because when I am editing, images will be reuploaded, and even if I removed an image from Dropzone (for images which have already been uploaded), that image will not be physically removed from the server. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: I need your help again. Do you know how to re-queue the images so that I can re-submit the page? This is an ajax submission. If the submission hits an error, and the user tries to re-submit the page (after fixing the values on other fields), the images in the Dropzone box is like not in the queue anymore, the user will have to add another image to be able to re-submit.

Comment: Actually, I'm a little confused - you already are *not* uploading the files *if* the `someFormValuesValidation()` function isn't giving a `true` result, so why would you want to re-queue the files?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Images are uploaded when the someFormValuesValidation() return true, but, there are further validations on the server end, so if some error occurred on the server end, then the page will display the error and the page stays. So, when this happens, it would be natural for the user to be able to resubmit after making amendments. Right now, the user will have to remove all images and re-add them.

Comment: I found another problem. Images are not being added or shown in the order/sequence as in imagesList. They appear rather random. Is there a way to make the images shown in the order/sequence as in imagesList? Note: I am using your updated for loop codes. Thanks.

Comment: Please help, I am still struggling with the problem of the images are being shown in random order in the Dropzone box. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, I'm really sorry, I had *completely* forgotten about this question - my bad. :/ I hope you found a solution/workaround, but if you still need help with the images order, let me know.

Comment: Hi.. really super glad that you are back. I am still stuck, the images order problem is still here, I have no solution. And, I have a new problem, in Microsoft Edge browser, the images do not appear at all (images which were already uploaded, they don't appear in the Dropzone box on the edit page). This new problem does not occur in Firefox and Chrome. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, from ideas here I constructed the following solution that worked for me:

```js
$.get(
  'attachments/actions/fetch-attachments.php',
  {
    parentdirectory: $fromparentdirectory,
    directory: $fromdirectory,
  },
  function (data) {
    var $files = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, row) {
      $files.push({
        name: row.name,
        size: row.size,
        dir: row.dir,
      });
    });

    if ($files) {
      for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
        let mockFile = {
          name: $files[i].name,
          size: $files[i].size,
          dataURL: $fromparentdirectory + $fromdirectory + $files[i].name,
          status: Dropzone.QUEUED,
          accepted: true,
          upload: {},
        };

        var ext = $files[i].name.split('.')[1];
        if (ext != 'png' && ext != 'jpg' && ext != 'jpeg') {
          var thumbnail = 'attachments/file.png';
        } else {
          var thumbnail = $fromparentdirectory + $fromdirectory + $files[i].name;
        }

        let name = $files[i];
        name = $files[i].dir + $files[i].name;

        console.log(name);

        fetch(name)
          .then((res) => res.blob())
          .then((blob) => {
            let file = new File([blob], name, blob);
            thisDropzone.addFile(file);
          });
      }
    }
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using v6 and @Sally CJ answer needed a slight hack. I hope it helps anyone in the same situation (I am using the min version).

Replace:
`b.append(T.name,T.data`

With: `if (typeof T.data.upload.uuid == 'undefined'){ T.data = new Blob(); }`

I was getting an error saying the 2nd parameter of append wasn't a Blob and this fixed it.